# Should I Add Invisible <h2>'s to <sections>'s?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

My site has a very nice, clean, html5 semantic structure.

But here and there, I have `section`s that don't have any `h2` tags because they are not worthy. For example, a box containing the progress bar for a networking tool. It does deserve its own separate `section`, but it absolutely does not need a header.

But the validator and other sites suggest *all* section tags need an `h2` header. Given that, should I add `display: none` `h2` headers to the few header-less `section` tags I have?

On the one hand, hidden content for the sake of making 'validators' and search engines happy seems like bad practice. If it's not worthy of being on your page, don't put it on your page.

**On the other hand**, I can see a situation where someone is using a text-only browser or some kind of visually impaired screen reader (that we always hear about in HTML docs but I've never heard of in real life). In that situation, you might not know what the progress bar even is. Looking at it's source code does not make it's function clear. But looking at it graphically rendered makes it 100% clear. So in that case, an `h2` tag that says "Progress Bar" would be useful to have in the source, while being invisible on the normally rendered page.

Comment: For a progress bar, a `<figure>` element is probably more semantic than a `<section>` element.

Comment: Does your `section` stand alone when taken out of the context of the page? If it does; does it have a title? If it does not then it should have a title. I personally suspect that your `section` does not stand well of itself so it should not be a `<section>` but should be within a larger section.

Comment: Screen readers will not read invisible content. Instead consider adding `title` attributes or aria markup.

Comment: @close-voters this is not opinion based. The MDN recommendation is pretty clear, sections should have headings, visible ones, and should not be used in this case. This is not an opinion, it's documented.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's not what then MDN docs say. Sections... "typically, but not always...have a heading."

Comment: Oh yes @sean. And it's assuredly not an hidden one, as is the actual topic of this question. In other words: this is not about wether or not there should be a heading, but if we should add an invisible one to a section that semantically should not happen. That's is very clearly discouraged in the specification. This is not opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem starts with misusing `<section>` tag.

Per MDN:

> The HTML  element represents a standalone section — which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it

A common misuse is using `section` as a devision element (using it as a wrapper) when really you could use a simple div.

**Usage notes of `<section>`:**

> Each  should be identified, typically by including a heading (- element) as a child of the  element.

And

> Do not use the  element as a generic container; this is what  is for, especially when the sectioning is only for styling purposes. A rule of thumb is that a section should logically appear in the outline of a document.

**About not worthy of headers sections**,
maybe a simple div to wrap progress bar elements can solve your problem .

With all that been said, MDN's states about `<section>`:

> — contained within an HTML document. Typically, but not always, sections have a heading.

Which means it's not "bad HTML" ...

More: [The Generic Section element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

About accessibility, there are other ways to interact with users. (titles for elements, alternative text and [more...](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_accessibility.asp))

Answer (score 0):

I personlly don't think you need to add element tags if they don't have any usage , it pollutes the page.

Comment: On the one hand, I agree. Though on the other hand, for a situation like a text-only browser or a screen reader, I could see it being difficult to know what the progress bar is, and in that case having an `h2` that just says "Progress Bar" could be helpful. -edit- I should add this comment to the original question.

Comment: I agree. I would recommend to add the h2 but just make it so it **not** stand out. ( think light color contrast, smaller text, ultra-light font-weight, ...)